# Does MailApp.sendEmail only work for Gmail accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have the following code attached to the OnBeforeDelete event in one of my data models in Google App Maker:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: 'example@email.com',
     cc: record.Resource.Manager.ManagerEmail ,
     subject: 'Deleted Allocation',
  body: 
  'February 2018: ' + record.February18 + '\n' +
  'March 2018: ' + record.March18 + '\n' + 
  'April 2018: ' + record.April18

});

}
```

This code, and similar code like it, used to send emails correctly to both my personal Gmail account and an Outlook account. Now, however, they are only being received by my Gmail account. I tested again with a simpler function:

```
function myFunction() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("example@email.com", "test mail", "why isnt this working");
}
```

Which confirms that it does not work when I type in the Outlook account instead of the placeholder email.

Does this only send email to Gmail accounts now (when it sent to Outlook earlier), or is there another explanation?

Comment: Did you look for this email in Spam box of your Outlook account?

Comment: Yes, I've looked in the Spam folder. The emails never appeared there originally, nor are they there now. I'm checking with my org to see if they introduced some email filters recently that would have caused this now.

Answer (score 0):

MailApp service does not have such restrictions; it can be used to send email to any address. Your test function `myFunction` worked as intended when I put in my (non-Gmail-related) email address in it.

If email is not being received, look for reasons on the receiving side. An overzealous spam filter may be to blame.

Comment: Thanks, checking on that end as well.